# Rebuilding indexes after Exchange Partition

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, indexing, oracle11g, materialized-views

Created A Materialized View On A Table.

SRC_TBL ---> MV

Doing exchange partition between materialized view and target table.

MV ---> TGT_TBL

Everythng is good so far. After Exchange Partition is done, am trying to enable indexes on target table. Data volume in Target is over 50million and therefore re-building indexes is taking time around 20min.

My query is how can I avoid or reduce index re-building time after Exchange Partition?

Appreciate your inputs.

Regards, 
Dex.

Answer (score 0):

Some potential options:

1) Use exclusively local indexes (obviously this is dependent on the application and your current design/implementation).  Then there are no index partitions to rebuild

2) Look at the "UPDATE INDEXES" clause when doing partition maintenance operations.  This slows the operation down, but leave the indexes usable at the completion of the task.